# Custom working directory Tomcat 7.0

Tags: tomcat

I am looking for a way to define a working directory for my webapps in Tomcat other than (tomcat_installation/bin)
I have tried Eclipse and was able to set the custom working directory under Run configuration -> Arguments -> Working directory -> Others 
However, I wonder if is there a way to do this without the Eclipse IDE?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the `workDir` attribute of your [Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html).

Comment: hi Mark, I have added workDir="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache Tomcat 7.0.41/webapps/myapp" attribute to the server.xml file under C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\conf
However, when I use the code System.getProperty("user.dir") to get the executing path, I still get to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\bin
Setting Working Directory in Eclipse will return the executing path correctly.
Do you have any solution that I can get this attribute from conf files?

Comment: If you mean a per web application "current" directory that is not supported. The "current" directory is set JVM wide.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Even if I want to set the "current" directory set by JVM wide, the System.getProperty("user.dir") still points to "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.41\bin" with workDir set to another location. Are there any ways I can set this "current" directory?